# SUM COUNT DISTINCT in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to count how many distinct agents there are where everyday between 2019-11-25 and 2019-11-27 and present the overall sum from this table (`call_logs`)

```
call_start  agent    source
2019-11-25  A222    campaign
2019-11-25  A111    campaign
2019-11-25  A222    campaign
2019-11-25  A111    campaign
2019-11-25  A111    campaign
2019-11-26  A333    campaign
2019-11-26  A222    campaign
2019-11-26  A111    campaign
2019-11-27  A222    campaign
2019-11-27  A111    campaign
```

If I run a function that retrieves distinct workdays for each agent I get,

```
A111  3 - agent A111 worked three days
A222  3 - agent A222 worked three days
A333  1, - agent A333 only worked one day
```

thus grouped by agent, or by date and distinct agents for each date

```
2019-11-25 2, 2 agents worked this day
2019-11-26 2, 2 agents worked this day
2019-11-27 3, 3 agents worked this day
```

But I'd like to be able to get the sum of 3+3+1 or 2+2+1 so that it's grouped through campaign and not date or agent,
like this: `campaign 7`

So that I have the information on how many workdays were used through those dates, in this case the 3 days.
If I try to SUM I get 28 or 23 instead of 7 workdays input.

I've tried to no avail the documentation and other posts here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first narrow our table to get what we want to count. We can select distinct triples of call_starts, agents, and sources easily enough.

```
SELECT DISTINCT call_start, agent, source FROM call_list;
```

This gets rid of multiple entries per day per agent per source. Now all we want to do is count how many there are per source. So we just need to use COUNT and GROUP BY source on what we got above.

```
SELECT Count(*), source FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT call_start, agent, source FROM call_list)
GROUP BY source;
```

This should give the desired result.